# How does let-to-rent tax work

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, rental-property

I’d like to let out my home in London for moving out to the country where I’d like to rent a bigger house.

Will I have to pay tax on the rental income without claiming the cost of the new rent?

Comment: Generally speaking, your own living expenses do not count as rental expenses; only costs directly associated with letting a property can be included (and even then, there are limitations, e.g. capital expenditure cannot be claimed; special rates for finance costs, etc). There are a lot of rules and regulations related to letting a property.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a page that gives an overview on [letting homes in the UK](https://www.gov.uk/renting-out-a-property/paying-tax).

**Your rental income counts as income** and you have to pay taxes on it, and possibly National Insurance. However **you can deduct some of the expenses you incur as part of letting the property**, and pay tax only on the profit.

Quoting the above:

> Allowable expenses are things you need to spend money on in the
> day-to-day running of the property, like:

- letting agents’ fees
- legal fees for lets of a year or less, or for    renewing a lease for
  less than 50 years
- accountants’ fees
- buildings and contents insurance
- maintenance and repairs to the property (but not improvements)
- utility bills, like gas, water and electricity
- rent, ground rent, service charges
- Council Tax
- services you pay for, like cleaning or gardening
- other direct costs of letting the property, like phone calls,
  stationery and advertising

There is also an allowance of a thousand pounds on which you don't have to pay tax.

**You cannot deduct the rent you are paying for where you live.** You couldn't deduct it if you didn't have the rental property and you can't deduct it when you do.

Comment: AFAICT, the £1000 allowance only applies if you're not also claiming allowable expenses. If your expenses are greater than £1000, then it's better to claim for them, instead of the allowance.